# changing a horizontal list to vertical

Tags: html, css

So I am working on a website and  want to know How I can convert the drop down list to be vertical. At the moment it's clunked up together horizontally. here is the code. I want to make the list in "services" to be a drop down list.
Html

```
<html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Lion" style="width:150px;height:150px;">
     <img src="logo2.png" alt="logo2" style="width:550px;height:150px;">
       <div id = "Navigation">
          <ul id = "nav-bars">
              <li> <a href = "#" >Home</a></li>
              <li> <a href = "#" >About Us</a></li>
              <li> <a href = "#" >Download</a></li>
              <li> <a href = "#" >Contact</a></li>
              <li> <a href = "#" >Services</a></li>
       </ul>
           <ul id = "services">

             <li>App Development</li>
             <li>Web Development</li>
             <li>Software Consulting</li>
           </ul>
       </div>
       <div id  = "registaration">
         <a id = "Login" href = "#">Login</a>
         <a id = "Signup" href = "#">Signup</a>
       </div>

   </body>


</html>
```

Css

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:   #BCD4E6;

}

li {
    float: left;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: "NavFont";
    src: url("NavFont.ttf");
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;


}
a{
    font-family: NavFont;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #ACE5EE;
}
#registaration{
     position:relative;
     bottom:200px;
     left:1300px;

}
#Login{padding:4px;}
#Signup{padding:4px;}
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#services li{

}
```

Comment: You try checking existing solutions like [CSS Wizardry](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/) has? The first step is to put your "Services" `ul` inside the "services" `li` tag.

Comment: The real question is, **How do I create a dropdown menu?** Please find a tutorial on the web on how to create one (there are many). This has been answered before and will likely get closed.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this, you will first have to put your submenu for services nested inside its parent nav item.

Like this:

```
 <ul id="nav-bars">
    <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Download</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul id="services">
        <li>App Development</li>
        <li>Web Development</li>
        <li>Software Consulting</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Then you will have to update some styles for your menu. For your parent nav `<ul>` style (should probably style it by id) you will need to remove the `overflow: hidden;` to allow the submenu to display, and add an `:after` style as a clearfix to clear the first level of floated `<li>`'s

```
#nav-bars {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #BCD4E6;
}

#nav-bars:after {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Next add `position: relative;` to your `<li>` so you can position the submenu off of it

```
li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

Next style your submenu to be hidden by default and to only show on hover of the parent `<li>`

```
li.dropdown:hover > ul {
  display: block
}

#nav-bars > li.dropdown > ul {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;

  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #BCD4E6
}
```

And lastly, to your original question, to get the submenu items to stack vertically simply remove the `float:left;`

```
#nav-bars > li.dropdown > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
```

Example:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #BCD4E6;
}

ul:after {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  clear: both;
}

li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

li:hover > ul {
  display: block
}

ul > li > ul {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

ul > li > ul > li {
  float: none;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "NavFont";
  src: url("NavFont.ttf");
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  font-family: NavFont;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #ACE5EE;
}

#registaration {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 200px;
  left: 1300px;
}

#Login {
  padding: 4px;
}

#Signup {
  padding: 4px;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#services li {}
```

```html
<img src="logo.png" alt="Lion" style="width:150px;height:150px;">
<img src="logo2.png" alt="logo2" style="width:550px;height:150px;">
<div id="Navigation">
  <ul id="nav-bars">
    <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Download</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul id="services">

        <li>App Development</li>
        <li>Web Development</li>
        <li>Software Consulting</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<div id="registaration">
  <a id="Login" href="#">Login</a>
  <a id="Signup" href="#">Signup</a>
</div>
```

Comment: One improvement I would suggest for the OP is to use a CSS class to scope styles on the `<li>` that are dropdowns, i.e. `<li class="dropdown"><ul><li></li></ul></li>`. This way you do not have to worry about nested `<ul>` and `<li>` that might appear in the content of the page being affected by styles that were meant for a dropdown.

Comment: @hungerstar I agree... should also use the id for styling the main nav (`#nav-bars`) to avoid messing up other `<ul>`'s that might appear on the page. Will update answer

Answer (score 1):

In the solution I provided, .parent class handles the display mode on hover event. So you can add class="parent" to parent list items and put  as submenus.
Also, you need to relocate the child ul this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="logo.png" alt="Lion" style="width:150px;height:150px;">
        <img src="logo2.png" alt="logo2" style="width:550px;height:150px;">
        <div id = "Navigation">
            <ul id = "nav-bars">
                <li><a href = "#" >Home</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#" >About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#" >Download</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#" >Contact</a></li>
                <li class="parent">
                    <a href = "#">Services</a>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <ul id = "services">
                            <li>App Development</li>
                            <li>Web Development</li>
                            <li>Software Consulting</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id  = "registaration">
            <a id = "Login" href = "#">Login</a>
            <a id = "Signup" href = "#">Signup</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, modify your CSS as follows:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:   #BCD4E6;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "NavFont";
    src: url("NavFont.ttf");
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    font-family: NavFont;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #ACE5EE;
}
#registaration {
     position:relative;
     bottom:200px;
     left:1300px;
}
#Login {
    padding:4px;
}
#Signup {
    padding:4px;
}
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.dropdown {
    display: none;
    top: -9999em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
}
.parent:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
    top: auto;
}
#services li {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

Comment: The `<div>` wrapping the inner `<ul>` is unnecessary unless there is some advanced styling or behaviors involved.

Comment: Sure, I just tried to provide an extendable solution. So, "A tax funded religion" won't face to another problem while doing more with the menu in the future. In any case, it's not a big deal, right?

Comment: That's bit of an anti-pattern. Going off your suggestion one might as well wrap every element they can in the beginning for the off chance that it might be needed in the future. If you need to redesign/expanded/etc. the menu in the future, that's when you add in the extra markup. On a small sight with basic functionality it's _"not a big deal"_ to not cache element references with JS but it's still good practice to do so, i.e. using jQuery `$(el)` everywhere instead of `var $el = $(el)` and then using `$el` so you're not querying the DOM relentlessly.